# ehcache SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter adding X-XSS-Protection & X-Content-Type-Options

Tags: java, header, web, ehcache

I have SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter configured in my web.xml and it works fine but how would I go about adding some other stuff to the header like:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

I went to http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/web-caching for more info but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is in the code and in JavaDocs. For starters I would extend `SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter` and override `buildPage()`:

```
public class CustomHeadersPageCachingFilter extends SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter {

    @Override
    protected PageInfo buildPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws AlreadyGzippedException, Exception {
        PageInfo pageInfo = super.buildPage(request, response, chain);
        headers.add(new Header<String>("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"));
        headers.add(new Header<String>("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block"));
        return pageInfo;
    }
}
```

However JavaDoc for the method we are overriding states that:

> To control your own caching headers, use {@link `SimplePageCachingFilter`}.

`SimplePageCachingFilter` is a base class of `SimpleCachingHeadersPageCachingFilter` which are extending right now. However I think this comment suggests to use the former class if we want to use completely different headers. If we want to keep standard headers (added by the latter class via `super.buildPage()`) this approach seems valid.

Disclaimer: note that extending class's behavior by extending it and overriding some methods by first calling `super` version and adding some logic isn't the best OO technique.